# IntelliJ and TomEE 7.0.1 JMX not connected

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat8, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I want to deploy a WAR to an Apache Tomee via IntelliJ IDE. If I configure the server and start it, the IDE could not connect to the server.

I know that IntelliJ adds JMX parameters to the Java Opts so it can connect to it and deploy the archives. These parameters are not ignored as it was in older tomcats. The JMX ports gets open, but the IDE still complains that it cannot connect.

'Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.'

I event tried to enable these properties in the system.properties

```
tomee.remote.support = true
tomee.serialization.class.blacklist = -
tomee.serialization.class.whitelist = java.net.URI
openejb.system.apps = true
```

Anyone with a similar problem or an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with TomEE-7.0.1 and IDEA 2016.2.2. After commenting all these:

```
# tomee.remote.support = true
# tomee.serialization.class.blacklist = -
# tomee.serialization.class.whitelist = java.net.URI
# openejb.system.apps = true
```

in system.properties the war was deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
tomee.remote.support = true
openejb.system.apps = true
```

this is needed otherwise no way to use the remote deployer of tomee (idea relies on it)

```
tomee.serialization.class.*
```

are explained there http://tomee.apache.org/ejbd-transport.html.You can just blacklist "-" to say no blacklist (fine in dev)